# Why does the ESP32 have a built-in Hall sensor?

Tags: microcontroller, esp32, hall-effect

The ESP32 has a built-in Hall-effect sensor. I am wondering if there is some sort of reason behind this other than "it was a nice addition".

A lot of sites talk simply about using it, and not why Espressif decided to increase the complexity and add it.

To the best of my knowledge, there aren't any other microcontrollers with this built in, though I may be incorrect.

I would love to hear your thoughts!

Comment: Sadly we are not a discussiin forum.

Comment: A Hall sensor is actually perfectly compatible with CMOS processing, so adds virtually no cost. Depending on how the ADC is realized it is this essentially for free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is totally my personal opinion.

When the Espressif started to break into the existing MCU market, there were already too many good MCUs in the market. They had to release an MCU with much more features than other competitors.
Thus, they might tried to add features as much as possible.
Such standing out features of ESP32 are:

- WiFi and Bluetooth in a chip - ESP32, while other common RF MCUs can handle only one of WiFi or Bluetooth.
- Dual-core for better performance.
- Larger memory
- Built-in temperature sensor
- **Built-in Hall sensor**
- Touch-sensor compatible ADC input
- CAN bus support
- external flash memory support

Compared to the ESP32, other MCUs had only a subset of the above features at that time (and maybe still today?).

There are other factors that might helped the ESP32 being a success, e.g:

- Arduino support and mature framework ESP-IDF from the beginning of release
- still cheaper than competitors' products, while it had much more features integrated.

Supporting external flash memory also opened a big possibility for IoT applications. ESP32 could handle bigger-scale embedded web apps. Check this out for an example: [Creating a Svelte Web Application for ESP32](https://pcbcrew.com/blog/create-a-svelte-webapp-for-esp32)

After initial market success, they started releasing more specialized MCUs. For example, ESP32-H2 has single-core, ESP32-C3 supports BLE only, not the full Bluetooth protocol.
But at the beginning, they needed to add as many features as they could.

I think these made the ESP32 a success, though there were already big players like STM32, MSP430/C1x/C2x, nRF52, and many more.